# How to convert numeric value to date format

Tags: r

I imported `.csv` file containing a date in one field. But when I use `mode()` for that variable, it shows as numeric. My requirement is I need to filter the data for a given date range. Below is the input file. But I am not able to do it in any means.

```
2   NC  2885    23-09-2013  877.00  
3   NC  2885    24-09-2013  876.20
4   NC  2885    25-09-2013  876.25
5   NC  2885    26-09-2013  876.95  
6   NC  2885    27-09-2013  876.45
```

Comment: There's a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531812/r-select-row-by-year-and-month/22534471#22534471

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much about it but look into the R function `as.Date()`.  This can take a numeric or string.